# Costs when using Amazon S3 and Cloudfront for storing and display user upload images

Tags: amazon-s3, webserver, amazon-cloudfront

I run a popular website where users can upload and delete images to their account.  Currently my website is hosting on 2 linux servers, one web server and one database server.

I have a requirement to upgrade to use 2 web servers due to an increase in traffic.  The problem is I have 2TB of images on my web server which are continously added to and deleted.

We have been informed that the best way to proceed, instead of syncing the images between webservers, is to use amazon S3 to store the images and cloudfront to deliver the images.

I've calculated the costs based on 2TB of storage, 2 Million monthly put requests and 8000GB of data transfer and the cost is around $1000 a month.  This is pretty expensive compared to the costs now, as we get 15,000GB of bandwidth included in our hosting, so our costs are going to increase by $1000 per month.

Is there any better and cheaper solutions to using amazon AWS, or would you advise biting the bullet and paying the $1000 per month and using S3 and cloudfront?

Kind Regards

Answer (score -1):

calculus its pretty simple: 
For EC2: 
- price for storage is: $0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage for or $0.05 for magnetic 
- traffic price: $0.09 per GB OUT, additionally you would pay for ELB processing

for S3/CF: 
- price for storage is $0.0295 per GB (almost half than ec2 magnetic)
- price for CF varies from $0.085 to $0.250 depending on the region; prices are abit higher depending on where your costumer base its located, but you get better quality of service.

you can also use the online calculator: calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html